# JQuery Nested list's children toggling whole list

Tags: jquery, list, nested

I have a list that looks like this

```html
<ul>
   <li class="expandable">Game
     <ul>
        <li>Action</li>
        <li>RPG</li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="expandable">BBS
     <ul>
       <li class="expandable">Group 1
          <ul>
             <li>Board 1</li>
             <li>Board 2</li>
          </ul>
       </li>
       <li class="expandable">Group 2
          <ul>
             <li>Board 1</li>
          </ul>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

and some some JQuery code to collapse the lists.

```js
$('li.expandable').click(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').toggle();
});
```

Something like "Game" for instance works fine. However when I click any of the nested lists under BBS like Group 1, it causes Group 1 and 2 to collapse into BBS. Clicking BBS expands the list again and shows Group 1 collapsed. Is there a simple solution to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a `return false`.

What's happening is because your list is inside another list, it's triggering the click event on each. By adding the `return false`, it only fires for the first one.

Example at http://jsfiddle.net/4yyau/

Comment: Wow. I would have never guessed that. Thanks.

Comment: I wish i could hug you my dude, my hero my love.!!